# QGIS least cost path sum of several paths (robustness)

Tags: qgis-3, cost-path, cost-surface, least-cost

I use QGIS 3.16.
For a wildlife conectivity model I used the plugin Least-Cost Path. For robustness of paths I used 3 different cost rasters for the same start and end points.
I want to know which paths are calculated in all three cost rasters (very robust), which just in 2 cost raster(medium robustness) and which just in 1 (not robust).
How do I achieve this?
Idea: give value 1 to each path, merge the 3 layers and sum up the values so that the path shown in each cost raster gets value 3.

But which tool to take?
Or is there a better idea?

Comment: What does your path output look like, raster or vector data? Which values/attributes?

Comment: The actual output of least cost path analysis is a multilinestring vector with values of costs per path between each start and endpoint. i converted the vector into a raster where all paths have value one and the rest no data. i thought to go along the with raster instead of vector, but maybe it is better to use vector and assign different values (1 for path, 0 for no path)?

Comment: Another idea: what would be the command in Field calculator for the sum of the values? I did vectzorize the raster, resulting in a vector with value 1 for path and then aggregated it. The attribute table shows values of each path but not the sum of the segments where they overlap. I guess i could achieve this in Field calculator?

Comment: I found one possible solution, but probably time consuming: I used raster calculator to sum the three raster layer, this gives me the patches where all three paths overlap as far as I understand it. I again used raster calculator for summing up  just two layer for the robust paths 8did that 2 times for the rest of combination)